# I'm freeing memory twice - C++

Tags: c++

I have done this program where I check if my 'date' class is correct. The problem is that when I run my test program, it returned my the following error:

> - Error in `./bin/test': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000019c07c0 *

The job of this class is read and store a 'date'(a year) and a few events (allocated in a string array). For example, a object of this class would be: 1998 EVENT1 EVENT2 EVENT3.

Operator >> reads the next format:1908#Fantasmagorie#The Taming of the Shrew#The Thieving Hand#The Assassination of the Duke of Guise#A Visit to the Seaside

Well, my problem is that I'm deleting some pointer twice or freeing some memory twice, I have tried a lot of things but I don't know how to fix it (as you can see on my code, I have already tried to set all pointers to 0 when I delete them.):
Date class .h

```
#ifndef _date_HISTORICA_
#define _date_HISTORICA_
  
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
  
using namespace std;

class date{
private:
    int year;
    int eventsNum;
    int reserved;
    string * str;
    void resize(int r);
public:
    date();
    //date(int a, string *s, int n);
    date(const date& d);
    ~date();
    int getAge();
    void addEvent(string& s);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const date& d);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, date& d);
};



#endif
```

Date Class Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<date.h>

using namespace std;

void date::resize(int r)
{
    assert(r>=0);
    if(r!=this->reserved)
    {
     if(r!=0)
     {
        string * aux = new string[r];
        if(this->reserved>0)
        {
            int min=this->reserved<r?this->reserved:r;
            for(int i=0; i<min; i++)
                aux[i]=this->str[i];
            delete[] this->str;
            this->str=NULL;
        }
        this->str=aux;
        this->reserved=r;
        if(this->reserved<this->eventsNum)
            this->eventsNum=this->reserved;
     } else
     {
        if(this->reserved>0)
        {
            delete[] this->str;
            this->str=NULL;
        }
        this->year=0;
        this->eventsNum=0;
        this->reserved=0;
     }
    }
}

date::date() : year(0), eventsNum(0), reserved(0), str(0){}

date::date(const date& d)
{
    this->year=d.year;
    this->eventsNum=d.eventsNum;
    this->reserved=d.reserved;
    this->str=new string[this->reserved];
    for(int i=0; i<this->eventsNum; i++)
        this->str[i]=d.str[i];
}

date::~date()
{
    this->year=0;
    this->eventsNum=0;
    this->reserved=0;
    if(this->str)
    delete[] this->str;
    this->str=NULL;
}

int date::getAge(){return this->year;}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const date& d)
{
    os << d.year;
    for(int i=0; i<d.eventsNum; i++)
        os << '#' << d.str[i];
    os << endl;
    return os;
}

void date::addEvent(string& s){
    if (this->eventsNum == this->reserved){
       if (this->eventsNum==0)
          resize(1);
       else
          resize(2*this->reserved);
    }
    this->str[eventsNum]=s;
    eventsNum++;
 }

istream& operator>>(istream& is, date& d)
{
    string line; char c;
    is >> d.year >> c;
    getline(is, line);

    int n=1;
    for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
        if(line[i]=='#')
            n++;

    d.eventsNum=n;
    d.reserved=d.eventsNum;
    delete[] d.str;
    d.str=NULL;
    d.str=new string[n];

    stringstream ss(line);
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        getline(ss, d.str[i], '#');
    return is;
}
```

Test Program Class:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cronologia.h>
#include<date.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    cout <<  "STATE: IN PROGRESS" << endl;
    cout << "TEST: (2)" << endl;
    date d;

    ifstream f("./data/name.txt");

    while(f >> d)
    {
        cout << d;
    }
    date d1;
    cin >> d1;
    d=d1;
    cout << d << endl;


}
```

Example file (which should be read by date class):

```
1900#Sherlock Holmes Baffled#The Enchanted Drawing
1901#Star Theatre#Scrooge, or, Marley's Ghost
1902#A Trip to the Moon
1903#The Great Train Robbery#Life of an American Fireman
1904#The Impossible Voyage
1905#Adventures of Sherlock Holmes; or, Held for Ransom
1906#The Story of the Kelly Gang#Humorous Phases of Funny Faces#Dream of a Rarebit Fiend
1907#Ben Hur#L'Enfant prodigue
1908#Fantasmagorie#The Taming of the Shrew#The Thieving Hand#The Assassination of the Duke of Guise#A Visit to the Seaside
```

I'm so sorry for my English!

Comment: `d=d1;` = and where is your overloaded assignment operator and copy constructor? you may find this an interesting read: [The Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: The overloaded assignment operator and the copy constructor are already done. I'm going to add the .h file so you can see them better.

Comment: That would be helpful. Without them a genuine repro is suspect.

Comment: I know D:. That's why im asking this. I have been trying to fix the error but I dont know kow D:

Comment: Thanks. That header doesn't show any assignment operator overload declared, much less implemented, which is exactly what my first comment referenced. Without it, the default will be used, which shallow copies member variables (ie, your pointer). You end up with two objects pointing to the same data. Read the article. It discusses the problem and how best to address it. If you search for `[c++] rule of three` on this site you'll get *plenty* of hits for additional reference. (and fyi, a `std::vector` of `std::string` makes *all* of this go away).

Comment: OH I SEE. LOOOOL I'm so sorry, I thought that I had done it x'DDDD. I got confused with copy constructor. Im really sorry. I will try it! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Read about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). BTW, why should `str` be a *pointer*? `std::string`-s can be shared....

Comment: Here's a tip: Don't use `new`, and all these memory problems go away.  `std::make_unique`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no assignment overloading in your code, in the line

```
    d=d1;
```

All the members of `d1` will be copied to a new object `d` by value. Hence there will be two copies of the object `date` which have the same reference value in their member `str`. Those two will eventually get out of scope and both will be destructed. The first one will free the allocated memory while the other will try to free that same reference and that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a copy assignment operator:

```
void swap(date& other) 
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(year, other.year);
    swap(eventsNum, other.eventsNum);
    swap(reserved, other.reserved);
    swap(str, other.str);
}

date::date(const date& d) : year(other.year), eventsNum(other.eventsNum), reserved(other.reserved), str(new string[other.reserved])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < this->eventsNum; i++)
        this->str[i] = d.str[i];
}

date& date::operator = (const date& d)
{
    swap(*this, d);
    return *this;
}
```

Might also be nice to provide a move constructor..

Comment: This implementation is not exception-safe, produces memory leaks and does not handle self-assignment correctly. Copy & Swap should be used instead.

Comment: Leaks memory if `this` has string allocated.

Comment: Incorrect implementation...  Copy constructor need to be directly implemented. Then coy constructor and swap could be used to implement assignment operator. I recommend you to read **item 13** again in **Exceptional C++** book by Herb Sutter.

Comment: Removed my downvote because the implementation was fixed.